# Use ajax to populate select2 only on open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using the following code to fetch options from a database and populate a select2 on open. It works pretty well, but as soon as I start typing in the select2 search input box it also searches via the same ajax function. How can I just populate every time it opens, but then leave it there as long as it's opened?

Also since I'm using it to create tags I lost the ability to auto-select the new tag when I attached the ajax part, so instead of typing and pressing enter to add a tag, it's now stuck in search-land and I have to click on the newly created tag manually if I want it to be selected.

Any ideas?

```
function formatMenu (data) {
  if (!data.id) { return data.text; }
  var $data = $(
    '<nobr>' + data.text + '</nobr>'
  );
  return $data;
};

$('select').select2({
    templateSelection: formatMenu,
    dropdownCssClass: 'select2-menu',
    dropdownParent: $('#parent'),
    placeholder: '-',
    tags: true,
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "?ajax=get_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
         return {
           searchTerm: params.term
         };
        },
        processResults: function (response) {
          return {
             results: response
          };
        },
        cache: false
    },
    sorter: function(data) {
        return data.sort(function (a, b) {
            a = a.text.toLowerCase();
            b = b.text.toLowerCase();
            if (a > b) {
                return 1;
            } else if (a < b) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
    },
    createTag: function (params) {
        return {
            id: params.term,
            text: params.term
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Any hints? Thx!